# QOpenGLFramebufferObject::takeTexture unable to copy textures

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

Ok. I am using Qt with OpenGL. And my objective to copy textures into another object. I have a vector of my custom class objects. Each object contains a

```
class MyCustomClass {
  GLuint texture_id;

  //
  Other data members;
}
```

Its maintain a queue of `MyCustomClass` Objects. So, each of the time I create an object to MyCustomClass, I try to copy the texture into it. I am using the `QOpenGLFramebufferObject::takeTexture` to create a copy of the texture & put its ownership into `MyCustomClass`. Like so,

```
MyCustomClass ObjectMyCustomClass;
QOpenGLFramebufferObject currently_rendered_texture;
ObjectMyCustomClass.texture_id = currently_rendered_texture.takeTexture();
```

But seems like takeTexture is not doing what it claims in my amateur OpenGL implementation.

All I want to create a copy of the texture in a `ObjectMyCustomClass` which I can use later to render in a special use case that I have. **What is wrong with what I am doing?** I noticed that when I try to access the copies of the texture later, i get the ID of the last texture I had copied using `takeTexture`. What is going wrong here ?

**Or is there a preferred way to copy textures in Qt OpenGL ?**

Blog below clearly states that I can copy & take ownership of the texture by calling [takeTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#takeTexture)

https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/09/21/using-modern-opengl-es-features-with-qopenglframebufferobject-in-qt-5-6/

Comment: When you say that you want to copy the texture, you mean you want to create a *new texture* which contains a copy of the data in the old one, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes. I want to create a new one. very much like a copy constructor in C++

Comment: @NicolBolas Am I missing some call to `new` or `glGenTextures` or something else. Sorry, I am newbie in OpenGL :)

Comment: Ok. This now works on OSX but doesn't work on iOS. I get a gl error complaining incomplete framebuffer attachment. Any hints or pointers pls ?